# disable a jquery mobile select with knockout

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

is that possible to disable with knockout a jquery mobile select like this:

```
 <select>
       <option value="1">value1</option>
       <option value="2">value2</option>
       <option value="3">value3</option>
       <option value="4">value4</option>
  </select>
```

I tried something like this `<select data-bind="attr: {disabled: 'disabled'}">` but doesnt work

Comment: Can you put together an example which demonstrates your issue? Because  the code what you have posted should work. In fact it does work: http://jsbin.com/inezel/1/edit

Comment: hey thank for your responce...my select is something like this: <select data-mini="true" data-native-menu="false"            data-bind="value: admissionType, jqmOptions:$root.picklists.optionsAdmissionType, optionsText: 'listDescription', optionsValue: 'idList', event: {change: $root.admissionTypeCheck}, attr: {disabled: 'disabled'} "></select>

Comment: instead use the enable binding

Comment: with the enable binding i have the same issue...but if i remove  data-native-menu="false" in my select seem to work for me...but i don't want to remove that attribute....

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with knockout.js only if select is a native one.

If it is styled with jQM then only way to disable it to use jQuery Mobile function like this:

```
$('select').selectmenu('disable');
```

or:

```
$('select').selectmenu('enable');
```